# Use a different graphics path subfolder for pictures

Tags: graphics

I write my thesis first time in Latex and tried to give a good structure to the document with a root document and different subdocuments I include with `\input`.
Here is a mini example of my tex document:

```
\documentclass[twoside,paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,draft]{scrreprt}
\input{preface/thesis_preambel}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\include{preface/thesis_titlepage}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\include{preface/thesis_day}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Motivation and Research Goals}
\input{chapter_motivation_and_research/thesis_intro}¸
\input{chapter_motivation_and_research/thesis_aim}
...
...
\end{document}
```

What I want now is to have a folder with pics:\home\thesis\pics
and for each chapter, I like to create a subfolder and save the pictures in it: \home\thesis\pics\thesis_intro and so on...

How must I include now the `\graphicspath{}` command? I only know how to do it with one path.
Can somebody help me and give me an example or advance?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `\graphicspath{{./path1/}{./path2/}...}`